# Set of left cosets and set of right cosets of a not normal subgroup could be equal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

**Question 1:**
Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. I would like to show an example for H, which is not normal, but the partition of $G$ into the left cosets of H is equal to the partition of $G$ into the right cosets of H.

*Example:*
A definition of the Dihedral group of order 6 is $D_3=gp\{c,b\}\ ,\ c^3=b^2=(bc)^2=e$. It follows from the definition, that $D_3=\{e,c,c^2,b,bc,bc^2\}$, and $bc=c^2b\ ,\ cb=bc^2$.

$H=\{e,b\}$ a subset of $D_3$.
H is not normal because $\exists c \in D_3: \  cH=\{c,bc^2\} \neq \{c,bc\}=Hc$

But the set of left cosets and the set of right cosets is the same:

Set of left cosets: $L=\{gH\ |\  \forall g \in D_3\}=\Big\{\{e,b\},\{c,bc^2\},\{c^2,bc\}\Big\}$

Set of right cosets: $R=\{Hg\ |\  \forall g \in D_3\}=\Big\{\{e,b\},\{c,bc\},\{c^2,bc^2\}\Big\}$

So $R\neq L$

Refer to "coffeemath" 's answer a missed the calculation at first time, now i correct it. So it's not a counter example for Question 2.

**Question 2:**
Is the next statement is true?

H is not normal $\ \Rightarrow \ \exists a \in G : aH\neq Hb \quad \forall b \in G $

I only see, that (from the negate of the definition of a normal subgroup)

H is not normal $\ \Rightarrow \ \exists a \in G : aH\neq Ha $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $aH=Hb$ then $a=ae\in aH=Hb$ so that $Hb=Ha$.

So if the partitions of left- and of right-cosets coincide then $aH=Ha$ for every $a$ and consequently $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

It's known that a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is normal iff every left coset of $H$ is also a right coset of $H.$

Could you include in your question the calculation result for your example the left cosets and the right cosets of $H=\{e,b\}$ please?